# MySQL is using wrong index

Tags: mysql, index

This is my table:

```
- user_id INT (foreign key on `user` with the reference `id`)
- question_id INT (foreign key on `question` with the reference `id`)
- option_id INT (foreign key on `option` with the reference `id`)
- exam_id INT (foreign key on `exam` with the reference `id`)
- order INT
```

My Index is: `user_id, exam_id`

My Query:

```
select * from `user_answer` where `user_id` = '48' and `exam_id` = '1' and `order` > '10' order by `order` desc limit 1;
```

I think it should use my index but this is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'user_answer', 'range', 'user_answer_exam_id_foreign,user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index', 'user_answer_exam_id_foreign', '4', NULL, '10', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Apperently, It is not using my index. When I use `FORCE INDEX`:

```
select * from `user_answer` force index (user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index) where `user_id` = '48' and `exam_id` = '1' and `order` > '10' order by `order` desc limit 1;

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'user_answer', 'ref', 'user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index', 'user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index', '8', 'const,const', '10', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Any idea what's wrong with me or MySQL ?

Comment: Include `order` in your index.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson I don't want to include it because I have some queries without `order` column so this index looks sufficient for me.

Comment: Also, rename the `order` column. `ORDER` is a SQL reserved word and should not be used for any object names

Comment: Follow Mark's suggestion. An index on `(user_id, exam_id, order)` is better for this query and it will still be used by queries that do not use `order` but only `user_id` and `exam_id`.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson @ybercube I just researched a little bit about this. Yeah you're right. I'll include `order` to my index. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will chose the index based on few factors. One of them is the cardinality of the indexed field, and other one in the number of rows to be scanned (on average). In your first example, MySQL decided that it will read less rows if it is used the index on "answer_id". 
If you provides the stats of your table, it will be much clearer. 
Example of data snapshot when this happens:

```
user_id answer_id order
48      1         15   
48      2         17
48      3         19
48      4         13
```

Here, if MySQL will see that user (User_id, answer_id) will scan 4 rows, while using (exam_id) will scan only 1 row.